# Set leaflet circle LatLng with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm having trouble creating a new circle on a Leaflet map with a variable as the `latlng`.

I have a form that contains and input for radius and a select box that contains a few locations with options looking like this:

```
<option value="52.10953576, -0.498735399999987">Place Name</option>
```

When the save button is clicked the following code is run:

```
$('#drawcircle').click(function() {
  var radius = document.getElementById("circleRadius").value;
  var e = document.getElementById("locationcoord");
  var latlng = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var radiusinmeters = cr * 1609.344;
  var circle = L.circle([latlng], radiusnmeters).addTo(map);
  drawnItems.addLayer(circle);
});
```

I have done some debugging with console.log and can see that the latlng variable does contain the correct information from the select box.

However, I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lng' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you get from `var latlng = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;` is a string, not a pair of coordinates.

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/split) this string to get your coordinates in an array, cast the values to numbers, and feed that to `L.circle`. For example,

```
var radiusinmeters = cr * 1609.344;
var latlng_string = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var latlng_array = latlng_string
                      .split(/,\s*/) // split the value
                      .map(function(v) { return +v; }); // cast to numbers

var circle = L.circle(latlng_array, radiusnmeters).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the variable latlng is a string, and L.circle accepts a LatLng Object, i.e. one of these:

```
L.latLng(<Number> latitude, <Number> longitude)
L.latLng(<Array> coords)    // [Number, Number]
L.latLng(<Object> coords)   // {lat: Number, lng: Number}
```

Your latlng variable is ["52.10953576, -0.498735399999987"]
You have to parse your string to get the correct values

more info in the [Circle Documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#circle)